# How display selected Key of a serialized Hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, json, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a serialized hash of a checkbox, and i would like to display just the selected keys.

**Model**

```
class Policy < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  serialize :shipping, JSON
end
```

**View**

```
<ul>
  <%= p.fields_for :shipping, @policy.shipping  do |s|%>
  <li><%= s.check_box :fedex %><%= s.label :fedex %></li>
  <li><%= s.check_box :dhl %><%= s.label :dhl %></li>
  <li><%= s.check_box :usps_10 %><%= s.label :usps %></li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

**BD**

```
{"fedex":"1","usps":"0","dhl":"0"}
```

**View Show**

```
<ul>
    <% if !@policy.shipping.nil? %>
      <% @policy.shipping.keys.each do |key|%>
        <li><%= key %></li>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `@policy.shipping` should be a plain old Hash so [`select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-select) should sort you out:

```
<ul>
  <% if @policy.shipping.present? %>
    <% @policy.shipping.select { |k, v| v == 1 }.keys.each do |key| %>
      <li><%= key %></li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

I'm not sure off the top of my head if you'll get `1` or `'1'` in your values though so you might need to `v == '1'` inside the `select` block.

You can skip the `.present?` (or `!...nil?`) check by taking advantage of the fact that `nil.to_a` is `[]` as well:

```
<ul>
  <% @policy.shipping.to_a.select { |k, v| v == 1 }.map(&:first).each do |key| %>
    <li><%= key %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Or even:

```
<ul>
  <% @policy.shipping.to_a.select { |k, v| v == 1 }.each do |a| %>
    <li><%= a.first %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

And you probably want to fix your original view to be properly nested or you might run into strange things in the future:

```
<ul>
  <%= p.fields_for :shipping, @policy.shipping  do |s|%>
    <li><%= s.check_box :fedex %><%= s.label :fedex %></li>
    <li><%= s.check_box :dhl %><%= s.label :dhl %></li>
    <li><%= s.check_box :usps_10 %><%= s.label :usps %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: mu! thank you very much man! i was almost breaking my neck trying to find the solution for this! yeah you will get '1' instead of 1